Empty Form when Editing Menus Typo3 8.7.32
I am trying to edit my menus, when I try to do it, it shows a text field with a 0.

When I add items to the menu it works fine, when I'm editing it shows 0.
Anyone have a clue about this?
I tried to recover files, in hope that it was a plugin update sort of.
I also tried to debug using console, doesn't show anything wrong
I read logs, nothing related to it

You are using a very outdated TYPO3 version, which is not supported anymore and has security issues. Regarding your problem: as you are using an ancient TYPO3 version, maybe there is an issue with modern browsers? So, consider updating your installation to a recent version.

In the Image you are in the list-module and editing any entity that you call menu. Sorry, but no one can help you that way.

It looks like an optional setting (see the checkbox) where you can enter a number of choice. The meaning of this number can be assumed only without further context.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
